# jquery checkbox operation help needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I don't how to do the coding in jquery for checkbox

```
<p class="list">
  <label for="chkSunday"><input type="checkbox" checked   name="chkday" id="chkday0" value="0" />All days</label>
  <label for="chkSunday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday1" value="1"  />Sunday</label>
  <label for="chkMonday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday2" value="2" />Monday</label>
  <label for="chkTuesday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday3" value="3" />Tuesday</label>
  <label for="chkWednesday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday4" value="4"  />Wednesday</label>
  <label for="chkThursday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday5" value="5" />Thursday</label>
  <label for="chkFriday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday6" value="6" />Friday</label>
  <label for="chkSaturday"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkday" id="chkday7" value="7"  />Saturday</label>
</p>
```

In above check boxes I have some use cases:

- Usecase 1

  - User selected any of the day then "all" check box should uncheck
- Use case 2

  - User unchecked all days then "all" check box should checked

I dont know how to handle this in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$(".list :checkbox").change(function() {
  if(this.id == "chkday0") $(".list :checkbox:gt(0)").attr("checked", false);
  $("#chkday0").attr("checked", $(".list :checkbox:gt(0):checked").length == 0);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PRzDn/).  What this is doing is rigging up a `change` handler to every checkbox in that `<p>`.

- If it's the first (all), clear all the other days.
- No matter which one it was, check the first if none others are selected (check All if no days).

Also note in the demo the `<label>` elements changed...they had invalid `for` attributes, and since they wrap the `<input>` they go with, you can just remove the `for` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to [@Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296769/jquery-checkbox-operation-help-needed/4296795#4296795), but avoids some of the DOM selection. It assumes a static group of elements.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/7UwLU/

```
var $allBoxes = $('p.list input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var $dayBoxes = $allBoxes.slice(1);
    if ($allBoxes[0].checked) $dayBoxes.not(this).attr('checked', '');
    $allBoxes[0].checked = !$dayBoxes.filter(':checked').length;
});
```

*No need to change the accepted answer. Just showing another way.*

Comment: @Elankeeran - You're welcome. Just throwing this one into the mix. :o)